# Error: Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, express, cloud9-ide

I am working in c9.io ide environment, I have written below code in server.js file

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var async = require('async');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var router = express();
var server = http.createServer(router);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function(){
  var addr = server.address();
  console.log("Server listening at", addr.address + ":" + addr.port);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});

app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('about');
});
```

After running node server.js in terminal the message given as

```
Your code is running at https://nodejs2-mujaffar.c9.io.
Important: use process.env.PORT as the port and process.env.IP as the host in your scripts!

Server listening at 0.0.0.0:8080
```

But after accessing https://nodejs2-mujaffar.c9.io/ url -- It is not rendering view only displaying message Error: Cannot GET /

What I am doing wrong?

Please help.

[image: Folder structure of app]

Comment: is the index.html file in the client/ root folder? I am assuming you're not wanting to used a view engine just straight HTML? Also, is there any reason why you have var app = express() and also var server = http.createServer?

Comment: Yes I am not using any view engine. For now just want to show plain html, I have edited question and added Folder structure image -- Please check.

Comment: check the answer by Varedis, I was going to point out the 2 instance issue but he already mentioned it. It seems like from your code, your app variable isn't listening on the port but the server is, 2 different instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have created two instances of express which may be your problem.

Try changing:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var router = express();
var server = http.createServer(router);
```

to:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);
```

At the minute, your express `app` variable is not bound to your http server. You have instead bounded an unused instance called `router`. But then you have registered your routes to the `app` variable.